# Go back to previous fragment after selection of date

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker

When user clicks on some date from datePicker then, how can i go to previous fragment from current activity. can i store that timestamp into my database actually i want to save that date in some variable and transfer it to my database. Plz help me i'm new in android

date_activity.java

```
public class DatePick extends AppCompatActivity {
DatePicker datep;
public long date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.date_layout);

    datep = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    date=calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("date", date);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Fragment.java

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 CardView cd= view.findViewById(R.id.card);
    cd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            date_Frag();
        }
    });
 }
   public void date_Frag() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), DatePick.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,11111);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 11111 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        long date = data.getExtras().getLong("date");
    }
```

Comment: You can save timestamp 
 using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html and if you just want previous fragment call    `finish();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you just want to close the activity** (and don't need to send back data), you can simply call `finish()` in the `DatePick` activity.

---

**If you want to send back data** from the `DatePick` activity back to your fragment, you can use `onActivityResult()`.

For example, first use `startActivityForResult` to start your second activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DatePick.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 11111);
```

Send back data from `DatePick` using `setResult`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("date", date);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And read it back in your fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 11111 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        long date = data.getExtras().getLong("date");
    }
}
```

---

[See this for detailed usage examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/1533054)

Comment: when i use startactivityforResult then its intent is not working. have Edited my code plz take a look

Comment: You're doing something wrong. `startActivityForResult` must be called in the first activity/fragment.

Comment: how can i add ok button to that datepicker for confirming the selected date by user.